# Error during SonarQube Scanner exection

Tags: javascript, java, sonarqube

I'm pretty new to analysing Code with SonarQube. Since i installed it, I ran twice in the "Java.OutOfMemoryError"-error. I tried  a few Things, suggested by others on this site.

**My configuration in SonarQube:**

```
  # WEB SERVER
# Web server is executed in a dedicated Java process. By default heap size is 512Mb.
# Use the following property to customize JVM options.
#    Recommendations:
#
#    The HotSpot Server VM is recommended. The property -server should be added if server mode
#    is not enabled by default on your environment:
#    http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/server-class.html
#
sonar.web.javaOpts=-Xmx4G -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -server

# Same as previous property, but allows to not repeat all other settings like -Xmx
#sonar.web.javaAdditionalOpts=

# Binding IP address. For servers with more than one IP address, this property specifies which
# address will be used for listening on the specified ports.
# By default, ports will be used on all IP addresses associated with the server.
#sonar.web.host=0.0.0.0

# Web context. When set, it must start with forward slash (for example /sonarqube).
# The default value is root context (empty value).
#sonar.web.context=
# TCP port for incoming HTTP connections. Default value is 9000.
#sonar.web.port=9000


# The maximum number of connections that the server will accept and process at any given time.
# When this number has been reached, the server will not accept any more connections until
# the number of connections falls below this value. The operating system may still accept connections
# based on the sonar.web.connections.acceptCount property. The default value is 50.
#sonar.web.http.maxThreads=50

# The minimum number of threads always kept running. The default value is 5.
#sonar.web.http.minThreads=5

# The maximum queue length for incoming connection requests when all possible request processing
# threads are in use. Any requests received when the queue is full will be refused.
# The default value is 25.
#sonar.web.http.acceptCount=25

# TCP port for incoming AJP connections. Disabled if value is -1. Disabled by default.
#sonar.ajp.port=-1


#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# COMPUTE ENGINE
# The Compute Engine is responsible for processing background tasks.
# Compute Engine is executed in a dedicated Java process. Default heap size is 512Mb.
# Use the following property to customize JVM options.
#    Recommendations:
#
#    The HotSpot Server VM is recommended. The property -server should be added if server mode
#    is not enabled by default on your environment:
#    http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/server-class.html
#
sonar.ce.javaOpts=-Xmx16G -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError  -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -server

# Same as previous property, but allows to not repeat all other settings like -Xmx
#sonar.ce.javaAdditionalOpts=
# The number of workers in the Compute Engine. Value must be greater than zero.
# By default the Compute Engine uses a single worker and therefore processes tasks one at a time.
#    Recommendations:
#
#    Using N workers will require N times as much Heap memory (see property
#    sonar.ce.javaOpts to tune heap) and produce N times as much IOs on disk, database and
#    Elasticsearch. The number of workers must suit your environment.
#sonar.ce.workerCount=1


#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# ELASTICSEARCH
# Elasticsearch is used to facilitate fast and accurate information retrieval.
# It is executed in a dedicated Java process. Default heap size is 1Gb.

# JVM options of Elasticsearch process
#    Recommendations:
#
#    Use HotSpot Server VM. The property -server should be added if server mode
#    is not enabled by default on your environment:
#    http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/server-class.html
#
sonar.search.javaOpts=-Xmx2G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true \
  -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 \
  -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError  -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit

# Same as previous property, but allows to not repeat all other settings like -Xmx
#sonar.search.javaAdditionalOpts=

# Elasticsearch port. Default is 9001. Use 0 to get a free port.
# As a security precaution, should be blocked by a firewall and not exposed to the Internet.
#sonar.search.port=9001

# Elasticsearch host. The search server will bind this address and the search client will connect to it.
# Default is 127.0.0.1.
# As a security precaution, should NOT be set to a publicly available address.
#sonar.search.host=127.0.0.1


#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**The error message:**

```
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
INFO: Final Memory: 41M/910M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)

at java.util.ArrayList.grow(Unknown Source)

at java.util.ArrayList.ensureExplicitCapacity(Unknown Source)

at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacityInternal(Unknown Source)

at java.util.ArrayList.add(Unknown Source)

at com.sonar.sslr.impl.typed.SyntaxTreeCreator.convertChildren(SyntaxTreeCreator.java:143)

at com.sonar.sslr.impl.typed.SyntaxTreeCreator.visitNonTerminal(SyntaxTreeCreator.java:119)

at com.sonar.sslr.impl.typed.SyntaxTreeCreator.visit(SyntaxTreeCreator.java:72)

at com.sonar.sslr.impl.typed.SyntaxTreeCreator.visitNonTerminal(SyntaxTreeCreator.java:89)

at com.sonar.sslr.impl.typed.SyntaxTreeCreator.visit(SyntaxTreeCreator.java:72)

at com.sonar.sslr.impl.typed.SyntaxTreeCreator.convertChildren(SyntaxTreeCreator.java:129)

at com.sonar.sslr.impl.typed.SyntaxTreeCreator.visitNonTerminal(SyntaxTreeCreator.java:119)

at com.sonar.sslr.impl.typed.SyntaxTreeCreator.visit(SyntaxTreeCreator.java:72)

at com.sonar.sslr.impl.typed.SyntaxTreeCreator.visitNonTerminal(SyntaxTreeCreator.java:89)

at com.sonar.sslr.impl.typed.SyntaxTreeCreator.visit(SyntaxTreeCreator.java:72)

at com.sonar.sslr.impl.typed.SyntaxTreeCreator.convertChildren(SyntaxTreeCreator.java:129)

at com.sonar.sslr.impl.typed.SyntaxTreeCreator.visitNonTerminal(SyntaxTreeCreator.java:119)

at com.sonar.sslr.impl.typed.SyntaxTreeCreator.visit(SyntaxTreeCreator.java:72)

at com.sonar.sslr.impl.typed.SyntaxTreeCreator.visitNonTerminal(SyntaxTreeCreator.java:89)

at com.sonar.sslr.impl.typed.SyntaxTreeCreator.visit(SyntaxTreeCreator.java:72)

at com.sonar.sslr.impl.typed.SyntaxTreeCreator.convertChildren(SyntaxTreeCreator.java:129)

at com.sonar.sslr.impl.typed.SyntaxTreeCreator.visitNonTerminal(SyntaxTreeCreator.java:119)

at com.sonar.sslr.impl.typed.SyntaxTreeCreator.visit(SyntaxTreeCreator.java:72)

at com.sonar.sslr.impl.typed.SyntaxTreeCreator.visitNonTerminal(SyntaxTreeCreator.java:89)

at com.sonar.sslr.impl.typed.SyntaxTreeCreator.visit(SyntaxTreeCreator.java:72)

at com.sonar.sslr.impl.typed.SyntaxTreeCreator.convertChildren(SyntaxTreeCreator.java:129)

at com.sonar.sslr.impl.typed.SyntaxTreeCreator.visitNonTerminal(SyntaxTreeCreator.java:119)

at com.sonar.sslr.impl.typed.SyntaxTreeCreator.visit(SyntaxTreeCreator.java:72)

at com.sonar.sslr.impl.typed.SyntaxTreeCreator.visitNonTerminal(SyntaxTreeCreator.java:89)

at com.sonar.sslr.impl.typed.SyntaxTreeCreator.visit(SyntaxTreeCreator.java:72)

at com.sonar.sslr.impl.typed.SyntaxTreeCreator.convertChildren(SyntaxTreeCreator.java:129)

at com.sonar.sslr.impl.typed.SyntaxTreeCreator.visitNonTerminal(SyntaxTreeCreator.java:119)

ERROR:

ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

System.Exception: Unexpected exit code received from batch file: 1

at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal.PowerShell.InvokeBatchScriptCmdlet.ProcessRecord()

at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()
```

**Things I already tried:**

1. Give SonarQube more Memory - As you might see in my configuration I changed the variable "sonar.web.javaOpts", "sonar.ce.javaOpts" and "sonar.search.javaOpts"
2. SonarQube ran into an error while analysing a ~1MB array. Since it were only test-data, I deleted the file and tried to run the analyse again. And yay! At least a different error....

   ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution

   ```
   org.sonar.squidbridge.api.AnalysisException: Unable to analyse file: C:/B/B01/15/s/src/org.scn.community.geovis/script/node_modules/grunt-contrib-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/compress.js

   at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.JavaScriptSquidSensor.analyse(JavaScriptSquidSensor.java:195)

   at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.JavaScriptSquidSensor.analyseFiles(JavaScriptSquidSensor.java:161)

   at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.JavaScriptSquidSensor.analyse(JavaScriptSquidSensor.java:152)

   at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:58)

   at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:50)

   at org.sonar.batch.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:83)

   at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:192)

   at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)

   at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)

   at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:241)

   at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:236)

   at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:226)

   at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)

   at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)

   at org.sonar.batch.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47)

   at org.sonar.batch.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86)

   at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)

   at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)

   at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:106)

   at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:119)

   at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:63)

   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)

   at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)

   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)

   at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:233)

   at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScanner.java:151)

   at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.runAnalysis(Main.java:123)

   at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:77)

   at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)

   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No break target can be found for label out

   at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:145)

   at org.sonar.javascript.cfg.ControlFlowGraphBuilder.visitBreakStatement(ControlFlowGraphBuilder.java:446)

   at org.sonar.javascript.cfg.ControlFlowGraphBuilder.build(ControlFlowGraphBuilder.java:223)

   at org.sonar.javascript.cfg.ControlFlowGraphBuilder.buildSubFlow(ControlFlowGraphBuilder.java:641)

   at org.sonar.javascript.cfg.ControlFlowGraphBuilder.visitIfStatement(ControlFlowGraphBuilder.java:458)

   at org.sonar.javascript.cfg.ControlFlowGraphBuilder.build(ControlFlowGraphBuilder.java:211)

   at org.sonar.javascript.cfg.ControlFlowGraphBuilder.build(ControlFlowGraphBuilder.java:199)

   at org.sonar.javascript.cfg.ControlFlowGraphBuilder.visitBlock(ControlFlowGraphBuilder.java:393)

   at org.sonar.javascript.cfg.ControlFlowGraphBuilder.build(ControlFlowGraphBuilder.java:227)

   at org.sonar.javascript.cfg.ControlFlowGraphBuilder.visitTryStatement(ControlFlowGraphBuilder.java:575)

   at org.sonar.javascript.cfg.ControlFlowGraphBuilder.build(ControlFlowGraphBuilder.java:231)

   at org.sonar.javascript.cfg.ControlFlowGraphBuilder.buildSubFlow(ControlFlowGraphBuilder.java:641)

   at org.sonar.javascript.cfg.ControlFlowGraphBuilder.visitIfStatement(ControlFlowGraphBuilder.java:458)

   at org.sonar.javascript.cfg.ControlFlowGraphBuilder.build(ControlFlowGraphBuilder.java:211)

   at org.sonar.javascript.cfg.ControlFlowGraphBuilder.visitLabelledStatement(ControlFlowGraphBuilder.java:535)

   at org.sonar.javascript.cfg.ControlFlowGraphBuilder.build(ControlFlowGraphBuilder.java:229)

   at org.sonar.javascript.cfg.ControlFlowGraphBuilder.build(ControlFlowGraphBuilder.java:199)

   at org.sonar.javascript.cfg.ControlFlowGraphBuilder.createGraph(ControlFlowGraphBuilder.java:161)

   at org.sonar.javascript.cfg.ControlFlowGraphBuilder.createGraph(ControlFlowGraphBuilder.java:156)

   at org.sonar.javascript.cfg.ControlFlowGraph.build(ControlFlowGraph.java:107)

   at org.sonar.javascript.checks.DeadStoreCheck.checkFunction(DeadStoreCheck.java:98)

   at org.sonar.javascript.checks.DeadStoreCheck.visitFunctionExpression(DeadStoreCheck.java:77)

   at org.sonar.javascript.tree.impl.expression.FunctionExpressionTreeImpl.accept(FunctionExpressionTreeImpl.java:174)

   at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.api.visitors.DoubleDispatchVisitor.scan(DoubleDispatchVisitor.java:114)

   at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.api.visitors.DoubleDispatchVisitor.scan(DoubleDispatchVisitor.java:125)

   at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.api.visitors.DoubleDispatchVisitor.visitParameterList(DoubleDispatchVisitor.java:222)

   at org.sonar.javascript.tree.impl.declaration.ParameterListTreeImpl.accept(ParameterListTreeImpl.java:98)

   at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.api.visitors.DoubleDispatchVisitor.scan(DoubleDispatchVisitor.java:114)

   at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.api.visitors.DoubleDispatchVisitor.visitCallExpression(DoubleDispatchVisitor.java:438)

   at org.sonar.javascript.tree.impl.expression.CallExpressionTreeImpl.accept(CallExpressionTreeImpl.java:68)

   at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.api.visitors.DoubleDispatchVisitor.scan(DoubleDispatchVisitor.java:114)

   at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.api.visitors.DoubleDispatchVisitor.visitExpressionStatement(DoubleDispatchVisitor.java:250)

   at org.sonar.javascript.tree.impl.statement.ExpressionStatementTreeImpl.accept(ExpressionStatementTreeImpl.java:66)

   at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.api.visitors.DoubleDispatchVisitor.scan(DoubleDispatchVisitor.java:114)

   at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.api.visitors.DoubleDispatchVisitor.scan(DoubleDispatchVisitor.java:125)

   at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.api.visitors.DoubleDispatchVisitor.visitBlock(DoubleDispatchVisitor.java:234)

   at org.sonar.javascript.tree.impl.statement.BlockTreeImpl.accept(BlockTreeImpl.java:83)

   at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.api.visitors.DoubleDispatchVisitor.scan(DoubleDispatchVisitor.java:114)

   at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.api.visitors.DoubleDispatchVisitor.visitFunctionExpression(DoubleDispatchVisitor.java:483)

   at org.sonar.javascript.checks.DeadStoreCheck.visitFunctionExpression(DeadStoreCheck.java:78)

   at org.sonar.javascript.tree.impl.expression.FunctionExpressionTreeImpl.accept(FunctionExpressionTreeImpl.java:174)

   at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.api.visitors.DoubleDispatchVisitor.scan(DoubleDispatchVisitor.java:114)

   at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.api.visitors.DoubleDispatchVisitor.visitParenthesisedExpression(DoubleDispatchVisitor.java:459)

   at org.sonar.javascript.tree.impl.expression.ParenthesisedExpressionTreeImpl.accept(ParenthesisedExpressionTreeImpl.java:80)

   at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.api.visitors.DoubleDispatchVisitor.scan(DoubleDispatchVisitor.java:114)

   at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.api.visitors.DoubleDispatchVisitor.visitCallExpression(DoubleDispatchVisitor.java:437)

   at org.sonar.javascript.tree.impl.expression.CallExpressionTreeImpl.accept(CallExpressionTreeImpl.java:68)

   at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.api.visitors.DoubleDispatchVisitor.scan(DoubleDispatchVisitor.java:114)

   at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.api.visitors.DoubleDispatchVisitor.visitExpressionStatement(DoubleDispatchVisitor.java:250)

   at org.sonar.javascript.tree.impl.statement.ExpressionStatementTreeImpl.accept(ExpressionStatementTreeImpl.java:66)

   at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.api.visitors.DoubleDispatchVisitor.scan(DoubleDispatchVisitor.java:114)

   at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.api.visitors.DoubleDispatchVisitor.scan(DoubleDispatchVisitor.java:125)

   at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.api.visitors.DoubleDispatchVisitor.visitModule(DoubleDispatchVisitor.java:146)

   at org.sonar.javascript.tree.impl.declaration.ModuleTreeImpl.accept(ModuleTreeImpl.java:56)

   at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.api.visitors.DoubleDispatchVisitor.scan(DoubleDispatchVisitor.java:114)

   at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.api.visitors.DoubleDispatchVisitor.visitScript(DoubleDispatchVisitor.java:141)

   at org.sonar.javascript.tree.impl.declaration.ScriptTreeImpl.accept(ScriptTreeImpl.java:73)

   at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.api.visitors.DoubleDispatchVisitor.scan(DoubleDispatchVisitor.java:114)

   at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.api.visitors.DoubleDispatchVisitor.scanTree(DoubleDispatchVisitor.java:109)

   at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.api.visitors.DoubleDispatchVisitorCheck.scanFile(DoubleDispatchVisitorCheck.java:34)

   at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.JavaScriptSquidSensor.scanFile(JavaScriptSquidSensor.java:232)

   at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.JavaScriptSquidSensor.analyse(JavaScriptSquidSensor.java:185)

   ... 31 more

   ERROR:

   ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

   System.Exception: Unexpected exit code received from batch file: 1

   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal.PowerShell.InvokeBatchScriptCmdlet.ProcessRecord()

   at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()
   ```

**The Code I tried to Analyse:** https://github.com/org-scn-design-studio-community/sdkpackage

So yeah, here I am, confused and without ideas how to proceed. Is anyone out there able to help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the 
[tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour),
 have a look around, and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) ,
 in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
 and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't exclude dependencies I suggest you go to your SonarQube's update center ( Administration/System/Update Center ) and install the latest version of SonarJS. I've tested that your issue does not appear in SonarJS 3.0 and above.

In general though, it's not a good idea to analyze dependencies. If your company wants to address security concerns on dependencies it's probably better to analyze the dependencies on their own, not as part of a larger project.

Comment: Hi Carlo, that was exactly what I needed :) I updated sonarJS to 3.1.1 and SonarJava 4.11. Now it works. Thank you again for your time and help

Answer (score 0):

The analysis fails on the following file:

```
C:/B/B01/15/s/src/org.scn.community.geovis/script/node_modules/grunt-contrib-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/compress.js
```

This is a dependency of your project and you shouldn't analyse it: you should only analyse the code of your project. Add the following line to your sonar-project.properties:

```
sonar.exclusions=**/node_modules/**/*
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Unfortunately it is a requirement from my Company, that the package, especially this third Party components, should be analysed.